# adding row to pandas dataframe from series

Tags: python, pandas

Let `df` be a `pandas.DataFrame` object. Let `se` be a `pandas.Series` object.

The columns of `df`, are the indices of `se`.

I wish to add a new row to `df` from `se` and set the index as `555`.

The command I use is `df.loc[555]=se`.

It works, it seems?

I get that *A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame* 
error/warning.

I get it, I've read the documentation.

Two questions though:

1. Should I really care about the warning?
2. What is the recommended way to go about this so that the warning doesn't pop up?

Thanks.

Comment: Any example of input data and expected output would be useful.

Comment: feels like a great answer was supplied without this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Should I really care about the warning?

It depends. In your example you are first referring to a subset of the data(`df.loc[555]`) and then setting values on this subset. Almost always pandas makes a `copy` of the original data and setting values on the copy will not modify the original Dataframe, hence the warning.

In some cases pandas will make a `view` of the original data(ex: if all columns have the same dtype.), setting values here will work as expected.

If all columns in your dataframe have the same dtype(ex: all floats) and you are using `iloc` on a single existing index then you are getting a view and the warning can be ignored. If you are setting on a non-existing index the you are [Setting with enlargment](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement), this is also the expected behaviour and the warning can also be ignored.

> 2. What is the recommended way to go about this so that the warning doesn't pop up?

Your use of `df.loc` given the info you provided seems alright. You have several alternatives to avoid the warning:

First, update your version of pandas. The situation with these false positive warnings has been improving with each version, I don't get any in 0.15.1.

Second, If you are sure that what you are doing is the intended behaviour then you can just silence the warning globally with:

```
pd.set_option('chained_assignment', None)
```

Finally, in some cases you can set the `is_copy` property of your resulting object effectively disabling the checks on this object, for example:

```
df_temp = df.loc[555]
df_temp.is_copy = False
```

Note that this last option can only be used on existing indexes, on new indexes this raises a `KeyError`.